# Updating Ember.js with moment.js, lost bower and now?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-addon

We have been using moment for the past few year in our software via [ember-moment](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-moment). After some time with production version frozen we are now updating. First step was to move up to 2.16 when we got the perception that we should not use shim any more, and so we don't know how to do regarding the moment dependency.

The goal is to update until most recent versions 3.x

Comment: why not use `ember-cli-moment-shim` anymore? while ember wants to make it easy to use it without such shim addons, its not bad to use them.

Answer (score 1):

just use `ember-moment`. `ember-moment` switched to using `npm` a while ago.
Actually `ember-moment` uses `ember-cli-moment-shim` which does all you need.
You can just remove `ember-moment`, `moment` and `ember-cli-moment-shim` from your `bower.json` and `package.json` and then do `ember install ember-moment` and it will install all of it to your `package.json`.